# How to increase or decrease days from a Dateformat ouptput in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have this format date example: 4 jun 2019

```
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
               formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd("fr_FR").format(now);
```

I tried now to increase or decrease days after pressed on the button but the previous code isn't compatible with :

```
var newDate= now.add(new Duration(days: changedate));
```

Comment: What type is changedate? You need to pass an int representing the number of days you want to increase... What the result of the last line ?

Comment: Yes, changedate is an Int that I increase or decrease with push of the button. the two line are separate, the output is ( 2019-06-04 15:51 ... .) Next I used regex to keep only 2019-06-04.

Comment: I didn't see the problem here... `now` it's a DateTime? what happens when you try to call `now.add(...)`?

Comment: var newDate= now.add(new Duration(days: changedate));  return date in the format  2019-06-04 I search to have 04 juin 2019 that why I start with the first code to fixe the dateformat, but the second code isn't compatible

Comment: I really doesn't understand what's the problem here.. you need your date formatted in `04 juin 2019` format, wright? What do you mean with "second code isn't compatible"?

Comment: I dont know ... I have the first code who have the good format but I don't succeded to modify the days with button, and the second code where I can change days but havn't the good format. It's possible simple but I don't see ... I'm noob :)

Comment: if you have a simple exemple ... to simply change days in the format 04 juin 2019, example : push button => days ++ => 05 juin 2019,  push button => days ++ => 06 juin 2019,  etc
it's will be very helpfull

Comment: Please, let me know if this example helps you... I think i didn't did much more than you wrote in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: define your formatter:

```
final _dateFormatter = DateFormat.yMMMMd("fr_FR");
```

Then you need to have a method that receives your date and the number of days (positive will increase days, negative will decrease):

```
DateTime changeDate(DateTime dtObj, int numberOfDays) {
    return dtObj.add(Duration(days: numberOfDays));
}
```

Then, when you need to show your date, you can format it:

```
String formattedDate = _dateFormatter.format(previouslyChangedDate);
print(formattedDate); //prints as: 4 juin 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase and Decrease of the day can be done by `DateTime` class

Initialize `DateFormat` which needed to be shown

```
  var _inputFormat = DateFormat('EE, d MMM yyyy');
  var _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
```

**Code:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            height: 40,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectedDate = DateTime(_selectedDate.year,
                        _selectedDate.month, _selectedDate.day - 1);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.exposure_minus_1_sharp),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Text(
                  _inputFormat.format(_selectedDate),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectedDate = DateTime(_selectedDate.year,
                        _selectedDate.month, _selectedDate.day + 1);
                    print(_inputFormat.format(_selectedDate));
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
```

**Output:**

[image]